# How to create Bot to Bot Dialogs (Nodejs/Typescript)

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I am having a bit of trouble establishing a bot to bot dialog conversation that allows for activities in MS teams such as update/delete activity etc. I have been trying to compare the botframework-solutions typescript VA/Skill samples, with botbuilder-samples (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot).

Generally I know the Typescript sdks tend to be a little bit behind the C#. However the design pattern being used for typescript in the Virtual Assistant example is completely different and uses the botbuilder-solutions library, specifically having both control differences for the parent and the skill bots needing to be done.. Since the skill client and necessary classes already exist in botbuilder, and there exist examples that require only minor changes to the skill bot, what is the "source of truth" for best recommended practices to accomplish bot to bot dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a Typescript variant of this does not exist yet. However, there is a Javascript sample, [80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot), that may work for you.

It is a basic demonstration showing how to send a message from a "root" bot to a "skill" bot that echoes back the original message. With some elbow grease you may be able to refactor to Typescript and build out the functionality you need.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Im very familiar with this sample and hence why I was specific in the tittle about Bot to Bot Dialogs as opposed to send a message from bot to bot. Will have to use that elbow grease to refactor the C sharp code I guess :)